# x86 - Does C uses virtual or linear addresses?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, memory-address

Suppose you are in x86 protected mode, so that segmentation is enabled.

Consider this code:

```
// main
int stackvar, *ptr;

// ptr may contain the address of a variable located in the stack segment
ptr = &stackvar;

// ptr may contain the address of a variable in the heap (data segment)
ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

I have read that `ptr` only contains the offset (i.e. virtual address) and doesn't contain the indication of the segment. This implies that it should be combined with the segment base address to obtain the linear address. Is it true?

```
// let %eax = ptr
asm("movl (%eax), %ebx"); // which segment is used by this instruction?
```

If `%eax` contains only the offset, and not the indication of the segment, how does the machine know which segment base address should be applied (e.g. data or stack segment base address)?

Comment: `printf("%p\n", (void*)ptr);`

Comment: That 286 operation mode was widely ignored.  Entertain us with the name of an operating system and compiler that uses it.

Comment: perhaps add a compiler/OS tag, this is certainly not something specified by standard C.

Comment: @HansPassant - wouldn't OS2/Warp and an appropriate compiler be the answer? From a quick glance, perhaps EMX as the compiler.

Comment: The knowledge about the default segment register is **hardcoded** in the processor. Also the segment registers are applied in the other protected modes, but they contain there not a part of the linear address but an entry in a descriptor table (e&oe).

Answer (score 3):

If an explicit segment override is not used, there are implicit segments attached to many opcodes - see assembler manual.

Comment: Is it possible that the segment override is memorized in the ptr variable in this case? I mean, I have debugged the above code and ptr gets the following values: 0xbffffcf8 (stack variable address) and 0x804a008 (heap variable address). Do they contain the segment indication or are only virtual addresses? If they are virtual addresses, I suppose - let me know if I am wrong - that it is compiler's duty to specify the segment override in the instruction (if the implicit segment is not what you want).

Answer (score 1):

You have confused 2 different concepts: offsets vs virtual address.

Unless you are an operating system (or a device driver), each process in a protected mode OS gets it's own address space.  And when I say that, I don't mean they get some part of the ~4gig of address space assigned to them.  I really mean that each and every process in x86 gets it's own ~4gig address space.

In this environment, it is perfectly possible that two completely unrelated applications running at the same time can both call malloc, and both get the same *address* returned.  This does NOT mean that they are pointing to the same data, however.  Address 0x804a008 from process1 isn't in any way related to address 0x804a008 from process2.

When the processes try to access that address, magic happens inside the processor (read about [TLBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer)) to turn a process' "address" into a physical memory location, resulting in an entirely different bit of memory getting read by each process.  This isn't something you see in the assembly dump.  The processor just does this every single time a protected mode application accesses memory.

So each process gets its own linear address space, and ptr really points to the address location.  When you say "ptr only contains the offset (i.e. virtual address)" that's not correct.  It contains the virtual address, period.  It's not offset from anything.

Way back in the dark days of 16bit, there really was a concept of segmented addressing.  What's more, processes all directly accessed physical memory and had a tendency to stomp on each other.  Unless I've misunderstood your question or your (unspecified) platform, that's not at all what's going on with that malloc.

To the kibitzers out there, yes, I'm simplifying.  People can (and have) written entire books about this stuff.

Comment: Yes, I already know this because I'm currently attending an "operating systems" class at university. Isn't the virtual address an offset relative to the segment? Yes, it is. My question was more practical. I.e. the virtual address may refer to different segments (inside the same process): if you only memorize the virtual address in the variable, how do you keep track of the segment to which that address was referring? I mean, dereferencing `ptr` works successfully with both stack and data addresses, so, how does C keeps track of the related segment (if this is not in the variable itself)?

Comment: One of the hardest things for anyone to do is to question their basic assumptions, but that's what you need to do here. If you were to set aside your continued assertion that there "must" be a segment here somewhere, the rest of your problems all disappear, don't they? If there isn't any segment, it doesn't need to be saved (or appear in asm dumps). Then the assembler dump you posted makes perfect sense.  A process gets 4gig.  It is used for code or stack or heap and the OS claims chunks, but 4gig is all you get.  And a single 32bit register is enough to reference any of that, no seg required.